# Portable solution instead of using Debian specific `column -n`

Tags: debian, rhel, opensuse, columns

I know that on Debian Linux distros, there is an extension `-n` flag to prevent `column` command from merging multiple adjacent delimiters into a single delimiter when using the `-t` option. But, I was wondering if there is a similar functionality on other non-Debian distros?

Comment: Though valid, it would be hard to check that in all of non-Debian distributions out there just to answer this question. Red Hat [does not seem to have it](https://www.unix.com/man-page/redhat/1/column/) for example, if that is up to date. Are you trying to emulate that behaviour with standard software? That's another question.

Comment: I have an script that uses `column -n` on Ubuntu and want to port it to other distros, such as RHEL. I am trying to not put too many if..elif... statements in the script. Maybe I can simulate the behavior using multiple `sed` commands, but it's not a clean solution.

Comment: If that's your goal, then start a new question asking just that: how to portably have the `-n` behaviour in systems lacking the patch. Ideally with a small text snippet with a sample input and another with the expected output. I'm pretty sure you will have many answers to choose from. And if you use the portable solution for all of them, you will not need the conditional statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna put this here in case somebody needed to replace 'column -n' with a portable solution:

```
sed -e 's/^,/#,/' -e ':loop' -e 's/,,/,#,/g' -e 't loop' | column -s, -t -x | sed -e 's/#/ /g'
```

Assuming the delimiter character is ',' we recursively replace the empty columns with a special character ('#' for this example), pipe it to `column`, then remove the special character at the end.